# extract 7z archive on linux web hosting

Tags: php, linux, 7zip

Would anyone know how to extract 7z archive on linux web hosting.
I am currently using the code below to unzip .zip files, but this does not work for .7z

```
// Unzip File 

$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open($userPath . 'import.7z') === TRUE) {
$zip->extractTo($userPath);
$zip->close();

} else {
echo 'failed';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The 7z file format can use various [compression algorithms](http://www.7-zip.org/7z.html), so you might be able to decompress the archive with one of the existing utilities for bzip2 or deflate.

You will likely need to use a library such as this one though. Here is the [latest version](http://download.modem-help.co.uk/non-modem/PHP/7z/7z.0.13.3.include.7z.php).

Comment: how do i use this file on the server? do you have any example commands?

Comment: You will need to include the file with require_once or include etc, and then just look through the file in your editor, its comments are pretty documenting they explain how to use it.

Comment: The link for this is dead. I've been looking for this for ages now but none of the links work! Please reupload!